# What happens when I call std::mem::drop with a reference instead of an owned value?

Tags: reference, rust, raii

```rust
fn main() {
    let k = "fire";

    drop(k);

    println!("{:?}", k);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a07ad067b84707f845e4be84af63598e)

Why am I still able to use `k` after dropping it? Does `drop` not deref a reference automatically? If yes, then why? What does the implementation of `Drop` look like for `&str`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What happens when I call `std::mem::drop` with a reference

The reference itself is dropped.

> a reference instead of an owned value

A reference **is** a value.

> Why am I still able to use `k` after dropping it?

Because immutable pointers implement `Copy`. You pass in a copy of the reference and it's dropped.

> Does `drop` not deref a reference automatically?

No, it does not.

> what does the implementation of `Drop` look like for `&str`?

There isn't one for any kind of reference, immutable or mutable, so it's *effectively* <sup>1</sup>:

```
impl Drop for &str {
    fn drop(&mut self) {}
}
```

See also:

- [Moved variable still borrowing after calling `drop`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428894/155423)
- [Why does a mutable reference to a dropped object still count as a mutable reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41732404/155423)

---

**1** — As [Peter Hall points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314407/what-happens-when-i-call-stdmemdrop-with-a-reference-instead-of-an-owned-val#comment97593974_55314470), there is a difference between having an empty `Drop` implementation and having no user-provided `Drop` implementation, but for the purposes of *this* question they are the same.

Comment: _"so it's effectively:..."_ — The mere fact of having a `Drop` impl has other implications, so this isn't _quite_ true..